# Z-Index and the map with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm trying to make a simple div (with a form to create a point in that location with some information) show up in front of the leaflet map when triggering the 'click' event on the map, but nothing is happening.

```
<div class="sixteen wide column"> 
        <p id="theMap" class="map">
              {{> mapp}}  
        </p>
        <div id="pointForm"></div>
  </div>
```

pointForm is what should show up and I have it some properties to show a simple box on CSS plus a z-index = -1.
(Using semanticUI and meteor)

Is this better done with a simple div+form or should I go for a popup+form ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: `pointForm` has no content to show in your example. Also, `z-index=-1` would put the div behind anything else. I strongly suspect that your issue lies with one of those two points.

Comment: I gave `pointForm` some css properties so it appears just a black box:
`#pointForm{
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: black; }`

I think my problem isn't that one right now as far as I tried. It seems that I can't even put the box in the same place as the map...

Comment: There is a bug in some CSS engines, where a div without content will always appear to have zero area. Try adding a space or other character in the div and see if it is visible then.

Comment: Hi, from research it seems that by default some leaflet elements have a z-index of 1000 or something, so since I just wanted to put a div on top of the map I styled it with `z-index=2000` and it's fine now.